# Why is this operator ($\hat{a}$)well defined (quantum physics)?

Tags: functional-analysis

My problem : if $x$ is a vector with components in that Hilbert basis $(x_i)$ (those coefficients must form a $l^2$ sequence according to basic Hilbert theory), then its "image" would have coefficients $\sqrt{n+1}x_{n+1}$ which is clearly not guaranteed to be a $l^2$ sequence due to the increasing unbounded $\sqrt{n+1}$ factor so the image is not well defined.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Indeed!  Most operators in quantum physics are not *bona fide* bounded linear transformations on the full Hilbert space, but instead [defined on a dense subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_defined_operator).